# Making a php array via variable reference

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, reference, associative-array

I am navigating through HTML DOM on PHP via a recursive function

HTML DOM , which is i am trying to convert into php array

```
<head> 
    <title> My New Web Page </title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<table>
    <tr><td><h1> Welcome to My Web Page! </h1></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><div>Menu item 1<div>Menu item 2</div></div></td></tr> 
</table> 
</body> 


$nodes_array[$recurse_count][$body_elem->tag] = $value;
```

Setting value to an array on every call to function and getting this as a result.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [body] => table
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [table] => tr
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tr] => td
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [td] => div
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [div] => div
        )

)
```

But i want to get this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [body] => Array
                (
                    [table] => Array
                    (
                        [tr] => 
                            [0]=>Array
                            (
                                [td] => div
                            )
                            [1]=>Array
                            (
                                [td] => Array
                                (
                                    [div] => div
                                )

                            )

                    )

        )

)
```

I tried to play with variable reference without enough knowledge.

function code ->

```
function recurve_extract($body_elem, $tag_str_name,$recurse_count)
    {
    global $nodes_array;
    global $recurve_level;

    if (sizeof($body_elem->children()) > 0);
        {

        foreach($body_elem->children() as $each_elem)
            {


            echo "<hr/>";
            echo $tag_str_name = $tag_str_name . '[' . $each_elem->tag . ']';

            $keys = explode('][', trim($tag_str_name, '[]'));

            print_r($keys);
        echo $body_elem->tag," == ".$each_elem->tag;




        //$value = array($each_elem->tag=>"");


        $value = $each_elem->tag;   


        //  setValue($nodes_array,$keys,$value);

        $nodes_array[$recurse_count][$body_elem->tag] = $value;


            if($recurse_count<10)
            {
            recurve_extract($each_elem, $tag_str_name,$recurse_count+1);
            }   


            }
        }
    }
    recurve_extract($body_elem, '[body]',1);
    print_r($nodes_array);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the function as it will be easier to change once we can se it.

Comment: @NigelRen done, function php code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to convert some of the code I have to almost get what you want, this though adds the content into each node....

```
$source = <<< XML
<html>
<head>
    <title> My New Web Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><td><h1> Welcome to My Web Page! </h1></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div>Menu item 1<div>Menu item 2</div></div></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
XML;

function extractXML( $base, SimpleXMLElement $node)
{
    $nodeName = $node->getName();
    $childNodes = $node->children();
    if ( count($childNodes) == 0 )  {
        $base[ $nodeName ] = (string)$node;
    }
    else    {
        $new = [];
        foreach ( $childNodes as $newNode ) {
            $new[] = extractXML($base, $newNode);
        }
        $base[$nodeName] = count($new)>1?$new:$new[0];
    }
    return $base;
}

$body_elem = simplexml_load_string($source);
$nodes_array = extractXML([], $body_elem->body);
print_r($nodes_array);
```

Recursive functions can be good, but you need to be very careful about what you pass in and what you pass back.  Using `global` adds more confusion, so try and make it more self contained.

What this routine does is pass in the content so far (`$base`) and the node to process (`$node`).  It loops over the content and at each point calls the same routine if there are sub-nodes.  Note that to start it off, I pass in the body tag to tell it where to extract from.

The output is...

```
Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [table] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tr] => Array
                                (
                                    [td] => Array
                                        (
                                            [h1] =>  Welcome to My Web Page! 
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [tr] => Array
                                (
                                    [td] => Array
                                        (
                                            [div] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [div] => Menu item 2
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: thanks this helped me a lot, i think yours code is in jquery. any way thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your recursive function, store the identifier of the parent elements, then when you store the actual value for an element, put it in `my_array[parent_level1][parent_level2][parent_level_x]`.

Comment: What if parent_level_2 have same keys like table ->tr and another tr, same keys will destroy the structure